# Parsing a deep level Json file and displaying the data in the frontend Angular

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, angular9

I have a data in the format:
data = {key1 : value1, key2 : [{key2_1: value2_1, key2_2: value2_2}], key3: value3, . . . keyn: valuen}

I want to parse the deep leveled json and display the data in the frontend in the following way using Angular 9:
key1 : value1\n (I am using \n to denote new lines) key2 :  (any spacing or indentation) key2_1: value2_1\n key2_2: value2_2\n key3: value3\n . .. keyn: valuen
If anyone can help, that will be highly appreciated.

```html
Value: any;
Key: any;
this.Value = Object.entries(this.data)
this.Key = Object.keys(this.data)

<html>
<ul >
    <li *ngFor = "let i of Value">{{i}}</li>
</ul>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide a more specific code snippet? there are lots of ways to do this.

Comment: I have added the html and the typescript file. ?I couldn't do a deep purse. Thanks a lot for reaching out.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a [pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) like `json` or create your own for more formatting:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let k of keys">
        {{k}}:{{data[k] | json}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbflt7?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code with me! I think that is not exactly I am looking at it. For the nested key, value pairs, I also want any kind of indentation or newline which rather than parsing the whole thing as json. It will look visually interesting.

Comment: @PriyankarBose I think a good option is for you to create your own custom pipe then. By doing so, you will provide a consistent way to handle this in other components in the future as well.

Comment: ! Thanks for your reply! Can you please show an example of making the pipe? I want to make it generic.